# How to convert image into Hex String in android?

Tags: java, android, hex, type-conversion, image-conversion

I am need to convert image into hex string to send it to web server. I am using this method to convert image to byte array

```
         BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         options.inSampleSize = 8; 
         Bitmap receipt = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.toString(),options);
         int size = receipt.getRowBytes() * receipt.getHeight();  
         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         receipt.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
         receiptbyte = stream.toByteArray();   
         String hexstring = toHex(receiptbyte);
```

and this to convert into hex

```
   public static String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, bytes); 
    return String.format("%0" + (bytes.length << 1) + "X", bi);
}
```

i want to produce the output as like

`c11ee236-8f72-4b60-9208-79977d61993f`

I am not sure what to do. Do i need to encode it?

Comment: take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314568/java-file-to-hex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you have like `c11ee236-8f72-4b60-9208-79977d61993f` is not an image - it looks more like an ID to an image stored on a server.

If you want the image you have to send the ID to the server and the server sends back the image data stored in it's database that belongs to the ID.

In Java you can generate such random IDs simply by yourself:

```
UUID u = UUID.randomUUID();
System.out.println(u.toString());
```

Outputs for example: `3aa5b32d-c6fb-43c5-80c9-78a1a35aff40`

Building your own server you can use this and save both image data and this ID into a database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Thats fabulous it not the image its id to the image... Do you know how to generate that id and link it to the server.. Actually this is what i am looking for.. please help me +1 for this answer

Comment: thats nice, but before seeing this answer i found that.. but your answer point towards right direction.. thanks i am marking as answer

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
//encode image to base64 string
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
 
        //decode base64 string to image
        imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/android-convert-image-base64-string-base64-string-image.html