# How to convert image to hexstring using JAVA (1.5)?

Tags: java, string, image, hex

I've been struggling with this for some time, and since I'm originally not a programmer, I'd appreciate any help.Here's the situation:

1. I have an image file on the file system, as well as converted to byteArrayOutputStream and to a ByteArray.(currently it's not critical which to choose, so any of these will work fine for input data)

2. I need to have the image represented as a string with the HEX code and a 0x prefix, like this:

Image -> String = '**0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010200000100010000FFDB0**'

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help! Any sample code or library will be appreciated!

Comment: This is the code that worked for me:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0596.html

Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
public static String getHexString(byte[] b) throws Exception {
  String result = "";
  for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
    result +=
          Integer.toString( ( b[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
  }
  return result;
}
```

Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#line.160):

```
String s = "0x" + Hex.encodeHexString(bytes);
```

Comment: But first you need some bytes, I think.

Comment: Yes, but the OP stated in his question that he already had the image as a byte array.

Comment: Hello,<p>Unfortunately with the commons-codec I always get this error:<p>java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.encodeHexString([B)Ljava/lang/String;<p>Any ideas? I tried two separate ways to transform the file into ByteArray but with the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: You compile your app with one version of the commons-codec library in the classpath, and run it with another version in the classpath.

Comment: Uhm, that's not the case. I compile it with ver 1.6 and have the same version (same file actually) copied to the directory that my app looks for external jar files.

Comment: If it were the same version, you wouldn't have such an error. Maybe you have some jar bundling a previous version.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like ready library to convert image to hex.You have to check this one topic:

[Java: File to Hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314568/java-file-to-hex)
:)

And if your hex is ready, you can convert it to string with method from another answer of @JB Nizet or try this library:

```
String hex = HexBin.encode(bytes[]); // add "0x" of course.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use HexString to store Image as string because it gains

data a lots.

You should use base-64 encoding for saving instead of hex encoding.

I recommend you to use `Base64` util of apache `commons-codec`

Answer (score 0):

this work with me

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(Image); 
          int c;
          String str="";
          while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        str +=  Integer.toString( ( c & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
         }
```